# Flutter Provider Nested Objects

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, provider

I'm using the [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to manage state in my Flutter App.  I am running into issues when I start nesting my objects.

A very simple example: Parent A has child of type B, which has child of type C, which has child of type D.  In child D, I want to manage a color attribute.  Code example below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class A with ChangeNotifier
{
    A() {_b = B();}

    B _b;
    B get b => _b;

    set b(B value)
    {
        _b = value;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}

class B with ChangeNotifier
{
    B() {_c = C();}

    C _c;
    C get c => _c;

    set c(C value)
    {
        _c = value;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}

class C with ChangeNotifier
{
    C() {_d = D();}

    D _d;
    D get d => _d;

    set d(D value)
    {
        _d = value;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}

class D with ChangeNotifier
{
    int                 _ColorIndex = 0;
    final List<Color>   _ColorList = [
        Colors.black,
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.green,
        Colors.purpleAccent
    ];

    D()
    {
        _color = Colors.red;
    }

    void ChangeColor()
    {
        if(_ColorIndex < _ColorList.length - 1)
        {
            _ColorIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            _ColorIndex = 0;
        }

        color = _ColorList[_ColorIndex];
    }

    Color _color;

    Color get color => _color;

    set color(Color value)
    {
        _color = value;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Now my **main.dart** (which is managing my `Placeholder()` widget) contains the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_example/NestedObjects.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: ChangeNotifierProvider<A>(
                builder: (context) => A(),
                child: MyHomePage()
            ),
        );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget
{

    @override
    State createState()
    {
        return _MyHomePageState();
    }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        A   a = Provider.of<A>(context);
        B   b = a.b;
        C   c = b.c;
        D   d = c.d;

        return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                            'Current selected Color',
                        ),
                        Placeholder(color: d.color,),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => ButtonPressed(context),
                tooltip: 'Increment',
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            ),
        );
    }

    void ButtonPressed(BuildContext aContext)
    {
        A   a = Provider.of<A>(context);
        B   b = a.b;
        C   c = b.c;
        D   d = c.d;

        d.ChangeColor();
    }
}
```

The above shows that the **Placeholder Widget**'s color attribute is defined by **Class D**'s color property `(A -> B -> C -> D.color)`. The above code is extremely simplified, but it does show the issue I'm having.

**Back to the point**: how would I assign *child D*'s color property to a widget, so that when updating *child D*'s property, it also automatically updates the widget (using `notifyListeners()`, not `setState()`).

I've used **Stateless**, **Stateful**, **Provider.of** and **Consumer**, all which gives me the same result.  Just to reiterate, the objects can't be decoupled, it has to have parent-child relationships.

---

**EDIT**

More complex example:

```
import 'dart:ui';

enum Manufacturer
{
    Airbus, Boeing, Embraer;
}

class Fleet
{
    List<Aircraft> Aircrafts;
}

class Aircraft
{
    Manufacturer        AircraftManufacturer;
    double              EmptyWeight;
    double              Length;
    List<Seat>          Seats;
    Map<int,CrewMember> CrewMembers;
}

class CrewMember
{
    String Name;
    String Surname;
}

class Seat
{
    int     Row;
    Color   SeatColor;
}
```

The above code is a simplified version of a real world example.  As you can imagine the rabbit hole can go deeper and deeper.  So, what I meant by the `A` through `D` example was trying to simplify the convolution of the situation.

Lets say for example you want to display and/or change a crew members' name in a widget.  In the app itself you would typically select an `Aircraft` from the `Fleet` (passed to widget by `List` index), then select a `CrewMember` from the `Aircraft` (passed by `Map` key) and then display/change the `Name` of `CrewMember`.

In the end your widget will be able to see what Crew Member's name you are referring to by using the passed in `Aircrafts` index and `CrewMembers` key.

I'm definitely open to a better architecture and designs.

Comment: have you tried `ProxyProvider` ?

Comment: Consider having one ChangeNotifierProvider per ChangeNotifier, and potentially use ChangeNotifierProxyProvider to make a ChangeNotifier that depends on another one

Comment: Possibility of doing this aside, this strikes me as an antipattern. Having `A` through `D` all implementing `ChangeNotifier` as well as being children of one another _as well as_ giving each of them a dedicated `Provider` (which you'd have to in order to get the nested classes to have their notifications processed correctly) sounds like a good way to start down a slippery slope toward dependency hell. I can't help but feel that whatever you need this for, there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Abion47 if that is what his dependency graph looks like, what would be a more efficient way to do it?  Use a global service locator instead of Provider?

Comment: @frank06 It's hard to say without knowing exactly why his dependency graph looks like that. Perhaps a global service provider, or perhaps having the different services available in general to pass to normal providers without needing to bring proxy providers into it. Or maybe not all of the classes really need to be change notifiers. Or just say screw it and bring in something like BLoC. All I know is that this whole example just has the sort of smell that hints at it being more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I added some more information to hopefully clarify my question a bit. @Abion47 I agree that this might be a slippery slope, but this is a very specialised app.  If anyone can give me a better design suggestion I'm all ears.  Maintaining this code is also a top priority.

Comment: @JBM see my updated answer. @Abion47 do you think my approach with `Provider` and `ChangeNotifier`s is scalable?

Comment: @RémiRousselet it would be great if you could chime in and give your opinion on my suggested approach (see answer to this question)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT: answer to the updated question, original below**

It was not clear what `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` stood for in your original question. Turns out those were *models*.

My current thinking is, wrap your app with  `MultiProvider`/`ProxyProvider` to provide *services*, not models.

Not sure how you are loading your data (if at all) but I assumed a service that asynchronously fetches your fleet. If your data is loaded by parts/models through different services (instead of all at once) you could add those to the `MultiProvider` and inject them in the appropriate widgets when you need to load more data.

The example below is fully functional. For the sake of simplicity, and since you asked about updating `name` as an example, I only made that property setter `notifyListeners()`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [Provider.value(value: Service())],
      child: MyApp()
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Consumer<Service>(
            builder: (context, service, _) {
              return FutureBuilder<Fleet>(
                future: service.getFleet(), // might want to memoize this future
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final member = snapshot.data.aircrafts[0].crewMembers[1];
                    return ShowCrewWidget(member);
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                }
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShowCrewWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  ShowCrewWidget(this._member);

  final CrewMember _member;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CrewMember>(
      create: (_) => _member,
      child: Consumer<CrewMember>(
        builder: (_, model, __) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onDoubleTap: () => model.name = 'Peter',
            child: Text(model.name)
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum Manufacturer {
    Airbus, Boeing, Embraer
}

class Fleet extends ChangeNotifier {
    List<Aircraft> aircrafts = [];
}

class Aircraft extends ChangeNotifier {
    Manufacturer        aircraftManufacturer;
    double              emptyWeight;
    double              length;
    List<Seat>          seats;
    Map<int,CrewMember> crewMembers;
}

class CrewMember extends ChangeNotifier {
  CrewMember(this._name);

  String _name;
  String surname;

  String get name => _name;
  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}

class Seat extends ChangeNotifier {
  int row;
  Color seatColor;
}

class Service {

  Future<Fleet> getFleet() {
    final c1 = CrewMember('Mary');
    final c2 = CrewMember('John');
    final a1 = Aircraft()..crewMembers = { 0: c1, 1: c2 };
    final f1 = Fleet()..aircrafts.add(a1);
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => f1);
  }

}
```

Run the app, wait 2 seconds for data to load, and you should see "John" which is crew member with id=1 in that map. Then double-tap the text and it should update to "Peter".

As you can notice, I am using top-level registering of services (`Provider.value(value: Service())`), and local-level registering of models (`ChangeNotifierProvider<CrewMember>(create: ...)`).

I think this architecture (with a reasonable amount of models) should be feasible.

Regarding the local-level provider, I find it a bit verbose, but there might be ways to make it shorter. Also, having some code generation library for models with setters to notify changes would be awesome.

(Do you have a C# background? I fixed your classes to be in line with Dart syntax.)

Let me know if this works for you.

---

If you want to use Provider you'll have to build the dependency graph with Provider.

(You could choose constructor injection, instead of setter injection)

This works:

```dart
main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<D>(create: (_) => D()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<D, C>(
          create: (_) => C(),
          update: (_, d, c) => c..d=d
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<C, B>(
          create: (_) => B(),
          update: (_, c, b) => b..c=c
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<B, A>(
          create: (_) => A(),
          update: (_, b, a) => a..b=b
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Flutter App',
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                          'Current selected Color',
                      ),
                      Consumer<D>(
                        builder: (context, d, _) => Placeholder(color: d.color)
                      ),
                  ],
              ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => Provider.of<D>(context, listen: false).color = Colors.black,
              tooltip: 'Increment',
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This app works based on your `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` classes.

Your example does not use proxies as it only uses `D` which has no dependencies. But you can see Provider has hooked up dependencies correctly with this example:

```dart
Consumer<A>(
  builder: (context, a, _) => Text(a.b.c.d.runtimeType.toString())
),
```

It will print out "D".

`ChangeColor()` did not work because it is not calling `notifyListeners()`.

There is no need to use a stateful widget on top of this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I added more information to my question.  The `Aircraft` object has two children `CrewMembers` and `Seats`.  How would you take into account these two *base children* in the answer (the objects not only being linearly related)? ( `ChangeColor()` should call `notifyListeners()` because it's declared in the `setter` )

Comment: To answer your question, no, I don't believe this is scalable. Every new model class you would add to your app means new providers, new change notifiers, new consumers, and it becomes a bit of a spaghettified mess. The problem is that in this approach to state management, you're effectively having the state manage itself. There's a reason that in state management libraries (and in architecture design in general) the "model" and the "controller" are two separate entities. Instead of having each class and subclass in the model manage updates, have one controller that manages it all.

Comment: @Abion47 in more concrete terms, what would be your suggestion? Ditch the notifiers in favor of something like a stream/BLoC?

Comment: While I agree with this can be "more complicated than it needs to be", BLoC is terrible in terms of boilerplate. Terrible. With enough models, I'd argue it's worse than notifiers.  Look at the official Todo sample app on the BLoC website – an insane amount of code for little functionality, too much liability for what it's worth.

Comment: @frank06 I agree that the boilerplate in flutter_bloc is a bit much, but that's also a necessary evil. Code simplicity can often come at the expense of architectural simplicity, and it's the latter that is far more important when talking about the maintainability of a project. If boilerplate code leads to a maintainable app while simple and straightforward code leads to a highly coupled app, which approach is better in the long run? (Also there are extensions for VS Code that help with the boilerplate immensely.)

Comment: In any case, I've posted my own answer on how I would approach the model classes.

Comment: @Abion47 just saw your answer. You raise valid points from an architectural standpoint as there definitely is less coupling with a manager and immutable models. Thanks for that, I understand exactly what you mean now.

Comment: Also to point out Remi's silent edit, you don't want to pass in a constructed value to the `.value` constructor of a provider. That constructor is for passing in pre-existing values. If you are creating the resource locally in that constructor, use the regular constructor with the `create` property. (See [`ChangeNotifierProvider` docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html))

Comment: Great answer, this example is worthy of adding to provider documentation. When a programmer comes to the question of how to deal with the model object hierarchy, she should be pointed to this example.

Answer (score 10):

As I've expressed before, the setup you have seems overly complicated. Every instance of a model class is a `ChangeNotifier` and is therefore responsible for maintaining itself. This is an architectural problem that is going to lead to scaling and maintenance issues down the line.

Just about every software architecture in existence has something in common - separate the state from the controller. Data should only just be data. It shouldn't need to concern itself with the operations of the rest of the program. Meanwhile, the controller (the bloc, the view model, the manager, the service, or whatever you want to call it) supplies the interface for the rest of the program to access or modify the data. In this way, we maintain a separation of concerns and reduce the number of points of interaction between services, thus greatly reducing relationships of dependency (which goes a long way toward keeping the program simple and maintainable).

In this case, a good fit might be the immutable state approach. In this approach, the model classes are just that - immutable. If you want to change something in a model, instead of updating a field, you swap out the entire model class instance. This might seem wasteful, but it actually creates several properties in your state management by design:

1. Without the ability to change fields directly, consumers of the model are forced to use update endpoints in the controller instead.
2. Each model class becomes a self-contained source of truth that no amount of refactoring in the rest of your program is going to affect, eliminating the side effects from over coupling.
3. Each instance represents an entirely new state for your program to exist, so with the proper listening mechanism (achieved here with provider) it's extremely simple to tell the program to update based on a state change.

Here's an example of how your model classes might be represented by immutable state management:

```dart
main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: FleetManager(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

...

class FleetManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _fleet = <String, Aircraft>{};
  Map<String, Aircraft> get fleet => Map.unmodifiable(_fleet);

  void updateAircraft(String id, Aircraft aircraft) {
    _fleet[id] = aircraft;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeAircraft(String id) {
    _fleet.remove(id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Aircraft {
  Aircraft({
    this.aircraftManufacturer,
    this.emptyWeight,
    this.length,
    this.seats = const {},
    this.crewMembers = const {},
  });

  final String aircraftManufacturer;
  final double emptyWeight;
  final double length;
  final Map<int, Seat> seats;
  final Map<int, CrewMember> crewMembers;

  Aircraft copyWith({
    String aircraftManufacturer,
    double emptyWeight,
    double length,
    Map<int, Seat> seats,
    Map<int, CrewMember> crewMembers,
  }) => Aircraft(
    aircraftManufacturer: aircraftManufacturer ?? this.aircraftManufacturer,
    emptyWeight: emptyWeight ?? this.emptyWeight,
    length: length ?? this.length,
    seats: seats ?? this.seats,
    crewMembers: crewMembers ?? this.crewMembers,
  );

  Aircraft withSeat(int id, Seat seat) {
    return Aircraft.copyWith(seats: {
      ...this.seats,
      id: seat,
    });
  }

  Aircraft withCrewMember(int id, CrewMember crewMember) {
    return Aircraft.copyWith(seats: {
      ...this.crewMembers,
      id: crewMember,
    });
  }
}

class CrewMember {
  CrewMember({
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
  });

  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;

  CrewMember copyWith({
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
  }) => CrewMember(
    firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
    lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
  );
}

class Seat {
  Seat({
    this.row,
    this.seatColor,
  });

  final int row;
  final Color seatColor;

  Seat copyWith({
    String row,
    String seatColor,
  }) => Seat(
    row: row ?? this.row,
    seatColor: seatColor ?? this.seatColor,
  );
}
```

Whenever you want to add, modify, or remove an aircraft from the fleet, you go through the `FleetManager`, not the individual models. For example, if I had a crewmember and I wanted to change their first name, I'd do it like this:

```dart
final oldCrewMember = oldAircraft.crewMembers[selectedCrewMemberId];
final newCrewMember = oldCrewMember.copyWith(firstName: 'Jane');
final newAircraft = oldAircraft.withCrewMember(selectedCrewMemberId, newCrewMember);
fleetManager.updateAircraft(aircraftId, newAircraft);
```

Sure, it's a bit more verbose than just `crewMember.firstName = 'Jane';`, but consider the architectural benefits in play here. With this approach, we don't have a massive web of inter-dependencies, where a change anywhere could have repercussions in a ton other places, some of which may be unintentional. There is only one state, so there is only one place where something could possibly change. Anything else listening to this change has to go through `FleetManager`, so there is only one point of interface to need to worry about - one point of failure as opposed to potentially dozens. With all this architectural security and simplicity, a bit more verbosity in the code is a worthwhile trade.

This is a bit of a simple example, and though there are definitely ways to improve it, there are packages to handle this sort of stuff for us anyway. For more robust executions of immutable state management, I'd recommend checking out the [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or [redux](https://pub.dev/packages/redux) packages. The redux package is essentially a direct port of Redux in React to Flutter, so if you have React experience you'll feel right at home. The flutter_bloc package takes a slightly less regimented approach to immutable state and also incorporates the finite state machine pattern, which further reduces the complexities surrounding how to tell what state your app is in at any given time.

(Also note that in this example, I changed the `Manufacturer` enum to just be a string field in the `Airline` class. This is because there are so many airline manufacturers in the world that it is going to be a chore keeping up with them all, and any manufacturer that isn't represented by the enum cannot be stored in the fleet model. Having it be a string is just one less thing you need to actively maintain.)

Comment: what did you think about Mobx,

Comment: @TDM I haven't tried using MobX in an actual project, so I don't know how scalable/maintainable it is in the long run. At first glance, it seems like a solid enough approach for people who like accessing everything using DAOs. Personally, I lean toward the simplicity and flexibility of using provider and ChangeNotifier together with my own homebrew MVVM approach, but that's a judgment call and a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Personally I mostly liked for changeNotifier + provider , I have done some testing apps with mobx , But it doesnt fit as ChangeNotifier. So I decided to use ChangeNotifier + Provider for my all future projects.   [Thanks for your thoughts about provider.]

Comment: I agree with this answer for the fundamentals of reducing complexity and globalising state á la Redux. I think the answer could be improved by showing how an individual UI entity might update itself in response to state changes. For example, how does one update a UI element representing an individual `CrewMember`? Are you supposed to use a `Provider.of<FleetManager>(context).fleet` and then search through for the member? Surely this has implications for re-rendering other UI elements that have not been changed? Is it possible, with this version, to use a `Consumer` for the `CrewMember`s?

Comment: @shennan With the Redux-style state management and reactivity paradigm, yes, you would rebuild all the dependencies of the entire fleet even if a single `CrewMember` was changed, and leave it up to Flutter to decide if it's worth rebuilding each `Element` if its corresponding `Widget` did or did not change. If this seems inefficient in this use case, that's because it is - and it's one of the shortcomings of the Redux-esque approach. If you want a setup that listens to individual `CrewMember` objects rather than the fleet as a whole, then that's a whole different answer.